# обратная сортировка выбором c#

Tags: c#

Господа, подскажите как сделать обратную сортировку массива выбором.Вот обычная сортировка выбором:

```
public static void SelectionSort(int[] massiv)
{
    if (massiv == null || massiv.Length < 2)
        return;
    for (int index = 0; index < massiv.Length; index++)
    {
        int minIndex = index;
        for (int next = index + 1; next < massiv.Length; next++)
        {
            if (massiv[minIndex] > massiv[next])
                minIndex = next;
            if (minIndex != index)
            {
                int tmp = massiv[index];
                massiv[index] = massiv[minIndex];
                massiv[minIndex] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправленный вариант вашего метода:

```
 public static void SelectionSort(int[] massiv)
 {
     if (massiv == null || massiv.Length < 2)
         return;
     for (int index = 0; index < massiv.Length - 1; index++)
     {
         int minIndex = index;
         for (int next = index + 1; next < massiv.Length; next++)
         {
             if (massiv[minIndex] > massiv[next])
                 minIndex = next;
         }
         int tmp = massiv[index];
         massiv[index] = massiv[minIndex];
         massiv[minIndex] = tmp;
     }
 }
```

В вашем варианте вы зачем-то делаете лишние перестановки внутри вложенного цикла. Сортировка выбором должна сначала находить минимальный элемент, а затем уже менять местами найденный элемент с текущим.

Чтобы поменять порядок сортировки на обратный, нужно поменять знак в условии `if` на противоположный, т.е. будет:

```
if (massiv[minIndex] < massiv[next])
```

Но при этом учтите, что имена переменных тоже желательно изменить (`minIndex -> maxIndex`).